# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el evento Activate y el evento Initialize? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Es lo mismo usar un formulario en el cual tendré un `listbox` con datos cargados:

```
Private Sub USerform_Initialize()
End Sub
```

Que el mismo formulario con:

```
Private Sub Userform_Activate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Son dos eventos totalmente distintos.

- [`Initialize()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event), es un evento que se ejecuta la primera vez que se crea el formulario o ventana. Por ejemplo cuando se carga un formulario aún sin mostrarlos con `Load Userform1`.
- [`Activate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.activate), por otro lado, se ejecuta cada vez que el formulario recibe el foco.

[`Initialize()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event) es un evento que deberías considerar como el primer evento en la carga de una formularios y [`Activate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.activate) como un evento que se ejecutará `n` veces, cada vez que la ventana reciba el foco.

Comment: Gracias  @PatricioMoracho ahora comprendo la diferencia entre los dos eventos.